# When to use static arrays vs dynamic arrays C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, dynamic, static

I'm kind of new to C and I was just wondering if there are situations where one is preferred over the other, if it just depends on ones preference or if there's one that is always better than the other.

Comment: It depends on the use-case and implementation.

Comment: There are two big questions: 1) Do you need to resize the array at run-time? And 2) Where do you want the array (on the heap, or "automatic" (stack) storage)?

Comment: Both are valid options, and have their use cases. In general, if you know the size of your array in advance and you don't want to resize it later, allocate on the stack. Otherwise, allocate on the heap.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The difference between “static” and “dyanmic” in this usage is either declaring `int a[3]` versus `int a[n]` in a block (in which case both are on the stack) or declaring dimensions as part of something else, such as a dynamic allocation like `int (*p)[2][3] = malloc(…);` versus `int (*p)[a][b] = malloc(…);`, in which case both are allocated and the difference is merely in code generation (hard-coded address calculations versus run-time multiplications by size. Changing the size from static (constant) to dynamic (variable length) generally does not change storage location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the word “static” has other meanings in C. You appear to be asking about the difference between declaring an array with a constant size, such as `int a[40]`, versus declaring an array with a variable length, such as `int a[n]`, where `n` is known at run time but generally not at compile time.

In this case, a general rule is to use a static size when you can:

- when the exact size is known at compile time, or
- when an upper bound is known and using the upper bound will not waste too much space.

In general, using a static size is more efficient because the compiler has more information and therefore has more opportunity for optimization. When the compiler is compiling address subscript operations, it has to generate instructions to calculate addresses. If it knows the array size, it may have opportunities to perform some of the calculations at compile time (e.g, for `int a[40]; a[13] = 2;`, the compiler can calculate that `a[13]` is 13•4 = 52 bytes from the start of `a` (assuming a four-byte `int`, of course) or to include the array size as an immediate operand in instructions (meaning it is built into the code and does not have to be looked up in memory or otherwise obtained at run time).

If the compiler does not know the array size, it must generate complete code to calculate addresses while the program is running. In today’s typical programming environments, this is usually not a great cost, but it may be a consideration.

Additionally, if an array has static size, it can be an external object (defined outside of any function). External objects have static storage duration, which means they exist for the lifetime of a running program. (Here, “static” is used in the C sense, different from the fixed-size sense.) When the compiler knows the size of an array, it can plan storage for it that is provided when the program starts. This enables an array with static size to have static storage duration. For an array with dynamic size, compilers generally cannot plan the necessary storage for them, so they cannot be external objects.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, this was what I was looking for. Do you recommend any particular documentation or book for more insight on this subject? I'm getting started in C coming from java and I'm really interested on how memory works in general.

Comment: @ZezePinto: C is more of a “do it yourself” language compared to Java. By and large, keeping things simpler is better—a fixed size is better than a variable size. C can still be learned from the Kernighan and Ritchie book, as a starting point.

Comment: Yeah that's what I've come to realize in the past weeks. Thanks again for your input, much appreciated